.NET 8 upgrade issue for functions using Durable functions and Orchestrator
I have upgraded function which uses Orchestrator and Durable functions from .Net 6 to .Net 8 (isolated model) and after upgrade when I am trying to run the function, I am getting the error

TaskActivityDispatcher-f287483ba94c4a169e710bad7fdb3c54-0: Failed to fetch a work-item: Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: The reader's MaxDepth of 64 has been exceeded.
Path 'OrchestrationTraceContexts[1].OrchestrationTraceContexts[1].OrchestrationTraceContexts[1].OrchestrationTraceContexts[1].OrchestrationTraceContexts[1].OrchestrationTraceContexts[1].OrchestrationTraceContexts[1].OrchestrationTraceContexts[1].OrchestrationTraceContexts[1].OrchestrationTraceContexts[1].OrchestrationTraceContexts[1].OrchestrationTraceContexts[1].OrchestrationTraceContexts[1].OrchestrationTraceContexts[1].OrchestrationTraceContexts[1].OrchestrationTraceContexts[1].OrchestrationTraceContexts[1].OrchestrationTraceContexts[1].OrchestrationTraceContexts[1].OrchestrationTraceContexts[1].OrchestrationTraceContexts[1].OrchestrationTraceContexts[1].OrchestrationTraceContexts[1].OrchestrationTraceContexts[1].OrchestrationTraceContexts[1].OrchestrationTraceContexts[1].OrchestrationTraceContexts[1].OrchestrationTraceContexts[1].OrchestrationTraceContexts[1].OrchestrationTraceContexts[1].OrchestrationTraceContexts[1].OrchestrationTraceContexts[0]', line 1, position 9935.

And I am using Newtonsoft to deserialize the json but after deserializing when it goes into Orchestrator triggered function during calling subOrcestrator function it won't process further.
error screenshot
Tried by adding the below configuration in host.json.
{
    "version": "2.0",
    "orchestrator": {
        "maxDepth": 128
    },
    "extensions": {
        "durableTask": {
            "serialization": {
                "maxDepth": 128
            },
            "tracing": {
                "distributedTracingEnabled": true,
                "distributedTracingProtocol": "W3CTraceContext"
            }
        }
    }
}

host.json screenshot
And also tried to set maxDepth property to 128 during deserializing but it's not working. Can someone please help with this?

Did you follow this doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-dotnet-isolated-overview

@Vivek Nirale, Can you try using system.text.json package.

The issue related to MaxDepth of 64 has been exceeded.
By giving MaxDepth  128 in host.json is worked.

The packages Newtonsoft.Json and System.Text.Json has been installed.

I have upgrated the orchestrated function to .NET 8.0 isolated. check the configuration below:
.csproj:
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.21.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.DurableTask" Version="1.1.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http" Version="3.1.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http.AspNetCore" Version="1.2.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.17.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService" Version="2.22.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.ApplicationInsights" Version="1.2.0" />
<PackageReference Include="System.Text.Json" Version="8.0.3" />
<PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.1" />

Function code:
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Http;
using Microsoft.DurableTask.Client;
using Microsoft.DurableTask.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace FunctionApp547296
{
    public static class Function1
    {
        [Function(nameof(RunOrchestrator))]
        public static async Task<List<string>> RunOrchestrator(
            [OrchestrationTrigger] TaskOrchestrationContext context)
        {
            var outputs = new List<string>();

            // Replace "hello" with the name of your Durable Activity Function.
            outputs.Add(await context.CallActivityAsync<string>(nameof(SayHello), "Tokyo"));
            outputs.Add(await context.CallActivityAsync<string>(nameof(SayHello), "Seattle"));
            outputs.Add(await context.CallActivityAsync<string>(nameof(SayHello), "London"));

            // returns ["Hello Tokyo!", "Hello Seattle!", "Hello London!"]
            return outputs;
        }

        [Function(nameof(SayHello))]
        public static string SayHello([ActivityTrigger] string name, FunctionContext context)
        {
            var logger = context.GetLogger("Function1");
            logger.LogInformation("Saying hello to {name}.", name);
            return $"Hello {name}!";
        }

        [Function(nameof(HttpStart))]
        public static async Task<HttpResponseData> HttpStart(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post")] HttpRequestData req,
            [DurableClient] DurableTaskClient starter,
            FunctionContext context)
        {
            var logger = context.GetLogger("Function1");

            // Function input comes from the request content.
            string instanceId = await starter.ScheduleNewOrchestrationInstanceAsync(nameof(RunOrchestrator), null);

            logger.LogInformation("Started orchestration with ID = '{instanceId}'.", instanceId);

            // Wait for the orchestration to complete
            var status = await starter.WaitForOrchestrationAsync(instanceId, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));

            // Create response JSON
            var responseContent = new
            {
                runtimeStatus = status?.RuntimeStatus.ToString(),
                input = (object)null, // Replace with actual input if needed
                output = status?.Output,
                createdTime = status?.CreatedTime ?? DateTime.UtcNow,
                lastUpdatedTime = status?.LastUpdatedTime ?? DateTime.UtcNow
            };

            string jsonResponse = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(responseContent);

            var response = req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            await response.WriteStringAsync(jsonResponse);

            return response;
        }
    }
}


host.json:
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "extensions": {
    "durableTask": {
      "jsonSerialization": {
        "maxDepth": 128
      },
      "tracing": {
        "distributedTracingEnabled": true,
        "distributedTracingProtocol": "W3CTraceContext"
      }
    }
  }
}

The Function ran successfully. check below:


Output:

